# Agregar valores al contexto para renderizar en Django

Tags: python, django

Pregunta traducida [de esta publicación en Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58384636), originalmente escrita por [Keyinator](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9854958/keyinator):

> Tengo el siguiente código dentro de una vista:
>
> ```
> return render(
>         request,
>         'home/index.html',
>         {
>             'mobile':False,
>             'title':'Home',
>             #'year': datetime.now().year,
>         }
>     )
> ```
>
> Así que solía calcular siempre el año en cada vista. Tenía que hacerlo
> ya que era necesario en mi layout.html
>
> Debido a eso, pensé que sería una buena idea extraer este cálculo para
> no tener que escribirlo específicamente en cada vista. Intenté esto
> usando el siguiente middleware:
>
> ```
> from datetime import datetime
> from django.utils.translation import gettext as _
>
> def get_vars(get_response):
>     def middleware(request):
>         request.year = datetime.now().year
>         return get_response(request)
>     return middleware
> ```
>
> Pero parece que la variable año no se agrega de la misma manera que
> sería en la vista.
>
> Entonces mi pregunta es:
>
> **¿Cómo puedo implementar esta funcionalidad?**
>
> **Si no es con un middleware, ¿cómo puedo hacerlo?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer lo mismo extendiendo el contexto global, me parece una manera mas sencilla y podrás acceder a los datos desde cualquier template:

Crear un archivo llamado `context_processors.py` en tu aplicasion.

En el archivo `context_processors.py` agrega la una función que hará el calculo:

```
from datetime import datetime

def ctx_dict(request):
    return {'year': datetime.now().year}
```

Ahora hay que registrarlo en el `settings.py` para que se inyecte en el contexto global, haciendo referencia a la función `ctx_dict`, de la siguiente manera:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'your_app.context_processors.ctx_dict', # Aqui
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Una ves hecho esto desde cualquier template tendrás acceso al valor de `year`, un ejemplo:

```
# template.html

<p>{{ year }}</p>
```

Espero haya sido de ayuda. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Quizás te sirva agregarlo directamente en el template con los tags incorporados que tiene el framework.
En la parte que se va a mostrar, en lugar de usar `{{ variable_anio }}` (trayéndola por contexto) podés usar `{% now Y %}`.
Podés leer más acerca de este tag en [la documentación](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#now).